# passing data into another activity with default values or custom values depending on user input

Tags: android

I am hoping if there is a way to pass 2 data variables from activity1(Technical) to activity2(User) where activity1 gives 2 current default values (x and y2) but also gives user the choice to input their own x and y2 variables if device has different dimensions.

There is a button for using custom values and a button for using device values dependant on user requirements. I would like to pass the required x and y2 variables into activity2(User) to calculate the required dimension. How do I pass these variables dependant on what user wants into activity2 please.

I am a relatively new user.

[Activity1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxxOv.png)

[Activity2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YFjr.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("x", yourX);
intent.putExtra("y", yourY);
startActivity(intent);
```

in the onCreate of NextActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  Intent intent = getIntent();

  int x = intent.getIntExtra("x",defaultValue);
  String y = intent.getStringExtra("y");
  if(y == null){
   y = yourDefaultYValue;
  }

  //do something with X and Y
}
```